# Run async function in the body of a scaffold

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I want to decide what content is displayed in the screen on the basis of a boolean variable called isAdmin. The value for this field is fetched from firestore.

Here's what I got so far:

```
Future<bool> isUserAnAdmin() async {
    var snap = await Firestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .document(UserSingleton().fireUser.uid)
        .get();
    UserSingleton().user = User.fromJson(snap.data);
    return UserSingleton().user.isAdmin;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("hemlp"),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onTap: () async => await Auth.logoutUser().then(
                    (value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/SignInPage')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: isUserAnAdmin() == true ? AdminPage() : PatientPage());
  }
```

The problem is that I'm always routed to PatientPage(), irrespective of the value of isAdmin. I suspect that this is happening because it isn't waiting for the value returned by isUserAnAdmin(). I thought I could just await isUserAnAdmin(), but I can't use await in the body of the Scaffold.

I thought I could resolve the issue by doing this:

```
body: isUserAnAdmin().then((value) {
          value == true ? AdminPage() : PatientPage(); 
        })
```

But I get an error that states:

```
The argument type 'Future<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.
```

Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You body should using a FutureBuilder:

```
body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: isUserAnAdmin(),
  builder: (context, data) {
    if (data.hasData && data.data) {
      return AdminPage();
    } else {
      return PatientPage();
    }
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a FutureBuilder in body.
This will call your async function and update when result is ready.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Future, u need to use await. But usually in widget, we use FutureBuilder instead:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("hemlp"),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onTap: () async => await Auth.logoutUser().then(
                    (value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/SignInPage')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: isUserAnAdmin(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
             if(snapshot.data == true) {
               return AdminPage();
             } else {
               return PatientPage();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }
);
  }
```