# Flutter Firebase real time database not storing values outside of listener code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

been stuck on this for a bit. Firebase Real Time Database using SDK.

I am able to successfully print the correct data in the original listening event but it does not seem to persist outside of it. Been trying a bunch of different things but the docs say this should work.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = {}; 

  DatabaseReference materials =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Users/${widget.uid}/materials');

  materials.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    map = event.snapshot.value as Map;
    print(map);
    print(map.keys.elementAt(0).toString());
    print(map.length); //HERE IT PRINTS 4 AS IT SHOULD AND ALL ABOVE DATA CORRECT
  });

  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
    appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(map.length.toString()), //HERE IT PRINTS 0 AND ALL THE REST OF THE CODE USING MAP VALUES ARE NULL
    ),
```

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134116/run-async-function-in-the-body-of-a-scaffold

Comment: Hey Evan, I was taking a look at it but I could not see my issue there. I am printing the correct values above, so the map does have the values, it just doesn't when using them in the return statement. Or possible I lack the knowledge to see how it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. Since the data is has to come from the network, it may take some time before it is available and happens asynchronously. Since your rendering code doesn't wait for that (it can't, as that would block the user from using the app), you `Text(map.length.toString())` uses the initial value of the map that you gave it here: `Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = {}`.

The solution is to either store the map in the state of the widget, as calling `setState` will cause Flutter to redraw the widget, or to [use a `StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to accomplish the same.

An example of that last approach would look something like this:

```
title: StreamBuilder(
  stream: materials.onValue,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && !event.hasError && event.data.snapshot.value != null) {
      map = snapshot.snapshot.value as Map
      return Text(map.length.toString())
    }
```

Comment: Hey Frank, I am a bit confused. What you are saying makes sense, I just was confused because in the first chunk, the answer gets returned right away with no await. I also set it equal to a variable and figured it was good. I am going to try the Stream builder but I do have a few other variables i need to get from it. Could you show me the first option? I tried putting it in the void setState() method but that did not work.